# python compare operator not working, if float(1) > float(1) evaluates to True, what am I missing?

Tags: python, floating-point, comparison, floating-point-precision

It's not exactly with 1 > 1 but close:

I want to compare two timestamps and do something `if time > timestamp` evaluates to `True`.
Both variables have the same `float` in them, as seen in pdb

```
(Pdb) print time
1396836917.98
(Pdb) print last_timestamp
1396836917.98
(Pdb) if time > last_timestamp: print 'wtf'
wtf
```

I would expect this to evaluate as `False`, it seems to be a `float` problem:

```
(Pdb) if float(time) > float(last_timestamp): print 'wtf'
wtf
```

`int` comparison works fine

```
(Pdb) if int(time) > int(last_timestamp): print 'wtf'
```

So I expected a problem with the precision of available bits representing the number

```
(Pdb) if float(time)*100 > float(last_timestamp)*100: print 'wtf'
wtf
```

but it still evaluates as `True` if there are no decimal places left ..

A work around for me right now is

```
if int(time*100) > int(last_timestamp*100): print 'wtf'
```

but I'd really love to understand what is going on and how to use the `>` operator correctly with `float`..

Answer (score 3):

Which version of Python are you using?  `print` implicitly invokes `str`, which in older versions of Python can hide differences between distinct floats.  Try printing `repr(time)` and `repr(last_timestamp)` instead.  If the floats are distinct, `repr` will produce different strings for them.

Comment: `Python 2.7.5+ (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:37:08) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.` I will give `repr()` a shot, but I gather the timestamps as `string` so there shouldn't be a difference ..

Comment: Try `repr`.  It doesn't matter where the timestamps came from.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a floating point understanding issue.

Basically except for certain rare numbers floating point numbers do not store numbers exactly, they store a number that is a tiny amount different from the one you think you are seeing. For example (1-0.8 != 0.2).

Here's an email I wrote about Java but virtually all languages have the same behavior:

Try calculating (int)(4.1-0.1) in Java (and anything else using the standard IEE floating point algorithms with truncating integer conversion) and the result you will get is 3.

For some more examples see:

http://ideone.com/ZseOnZ

If you convert the doubles to floats you get a completely different set of values which are wrong but for example (int)(4.2f-0.2f) gives the wrong result.

For SQL you can illustrate the same thing:

```
        select CONVERT(INTEGER, CONVERT(float, 4.1)-CONVERT(float, 0.1))
```

This gives a result of 3.